# How to ignore specific fields from being serialized?

Tags: scs

I'd like to ignore some fields from being serialized - for example:

- `Last run`
- `__Owner`
- `__Revision`
- `__Updated by`

Is there any configuration for this?

Comment: Doesn't look like it: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/developer-tools/en/sitecore-content-serialization-configuration-reference.html

Comment: There are tools that does this however.

Comment: If we have c# model class then we can do using 
[JsonIgnore] attribute, for reference please find below link
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm


But i can see properties which you mentioned are Sitecore Item's standard fields.
Can you please help me to know - with which mechanism you are serializing like unicorn or other?

Comment: Sitecore 10 Content Serialization

Answer (score 2):

> **The excluded fields feature is available from CLI 4.0 or later.**

You can add `"excludedFields"` in `sitecore.json` configuration file like that:

```
"excludedFields": [
  {
    "fieldId": "8cdc337e-a112-42fb-bbb4-4143751e123f",
    "description": "__Revision"
  },
  {
    "fieldId": "badd9cf9-53e0-4d0c-bcc0-2d784c282f6a",
    "description": "__Updated by"
  }]
```

So the full file could be like that:

```
{
  "$schema": "./.sitecore/schemas/RootConfigurationFile.schema.json",
  "modules": [
    "../../../src/*/*/*/*.module.json"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Serialization@4.0.0",
    "Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Publishing@4.0.0"
  ],
  "serialization": {
    "defaultMaxRelativeItemPathLength": 100,
    "defaultModuleRelativeSerializationPath": "../serialization",
    "removeOrphansForRoles": true,
    "excludedFields": [
      {
        "fieldId": "8cdc337e-a112-42fb-bbb4-4143751e123f",
        "description": "__Revision"
      },
      {
        "fieldId": "badd9cf9-53e0-4d0c-bcc0-2d784c282f6a",
        "description": "__Updated by"
      },
      {
        "fieldId": "d9cf14b1-fa16-4ba6-9288-e8a174d4d522",
        "description": "__Updated"
      },
      {
        "fieldId": "5dd74568-4d4b-44c1-b513-0af5f4cda34f",
        "description": "__Created by"
      },
      {
        "fieldId": "25bed78c-4957-4165-998a-ca1b52f67497",
        "description": "__Created"
      },
      {
        "fieldId": "{52807595-0F8F-4B20-8D2A-CB71D28C6103}",
        "description": "__Owner"
      },
      {
        "fieldId": "{001DD393-96C5-490B-924A-B0F25CD9EFD8}",
        "description": "__Lock"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can exclude fields per module as well. Same `excludedFields` setting in module file, right after `items`:

```
...
items": {
    "includes": [
        {
            "name": "Apikey",
            "path": "/sitecore/system/Settings/Services/API Keys"
        },
        {
            "name": "Media",
            "path": "/sitecore/media library/my-first-jss-app"
        }
    ],
    "excludedFields":[
        {
            "fieldID": "{EB504D1B-B612-4FFF-B239-CA3BD7273D1B}",
            "description": "FieldsForExclude1"
        },
        {
            "fieldID": "{3C2C061E-F61F-4DF6-89EA-0B7A56348737}",
            "description": "FieldsForExclude2"
        },

        {
            "fieldID": "{4F7446A4-79C8-4853-A357-723665FE68DA}",
            "description": "ExcludeUnversionFIeld"
        }
    ]
}
```

Sitecore documentation: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/developer-tools/sitecore-content-serialization-structural-overview.html

Comment: This answer should probably include, which version of the Sitecore CLI this feature was included in

Comment: Answer updated.